# Angular 6 - mock authState - valueChanges of undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine2.0, angular-test

I have a service with a property and a getter. The property is set in the service constructor like this:

```
public readonly usersMetaData: Observable<User | null>;

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.usersMetaData = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(switchMap((user: firebase.User) => {
        if (user) {
            return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
        } else {
            return of(null);
        }
    }), share());
}
```

My getter just tests if the authstate returns a defined object basically (not null, not undefined):

```
public isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.usersMetaData.pipe(map(user => !!user));
}
```

Now for my unit test setup, I need to mock authState from firebase. It looks as follows:

```
  let service: AuthService;

  const authStub: any = {
    authState: {}
  };

  const storeStub = {
    doc() {
      return of(null);
    }
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {provide: AngularFireAuth, useValue: authStub},
        {provide: AngularFirestore, useValue: storeStub},
        AuthService
      ]
    });

    authStub.authState = of({username: 'test'});
    spyOn(storeStub, 'doc').and.stub();
    service = TestBed.get(AuthService);
  });

  it('should check for authentication - is authenticated', async(() => {
    service.isAuthenticated().subscribe(isUser => console.log(isUser)); <== should return true
  }));
```

The error that is returning is: `Failed: Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of undefined`
Does anyone know how to mock authstate properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost right. The storeStub obj needs to be modified like this:

```
  const storeStub = {
    doc() {
      return {
        valueChanges() {
          return of({property: 'test'});
        }
      };
    }
  };
```

since doc calls valueChanges you need to return valueChanges in your mocked object.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be a Jest user finding this page, try:

```
const storeStub = {
    collection: jest.fn(),
    doc: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
        valueChanges: jest
            .fn()
            .mockImplementation(() => of(mockUserProfile)),
    })),
};
```